# exporting to fbx causes deformation

Tags: .fbx, surface-deform

So i have a model that started out of a vrm from vroid. I stripped it down a little as a basis for my own model. then edited it, and then added animations. but now its done, when i export it to fbx it deforms.

see image below for example

[image: example of problem]

1. What could be causing this
2. how can i fix it?
3. what more info do you need?

blender file = [image]

Comment: It looks like the bones aren't parented properly; have you double-checked that?

Comment: Importing the exported FBX file back into Blender seems to be working fine. If you're checking the file online, it may be converted to GLB or some other format on their end. Check to see if that website accepts GLB or glTF. If so, it may be best to just upload a GLB file directly.

Answer (score 0):

The FBX format is not an open source format, blender's fbx is its own format, so there may be errors, you can find an fbx plugin, should be perfectly exported